# Закрыть NodeJS скрипт через .bat файл

Tags: node.js, bat

Как реализовать закрытие NodeJS скрипта при помощи .bat файла?

Проблема в том, что я не знаю, какой процесс закрывать. При запуске скрипта появляется только процесс NodeJS и открывается консоль с логом.

Comment: может быть вам лучше попробовать управление "скриптом" через pm2?

Comment: Самый примитивный вариант: запускать скрипт в batch-файле. В батнике в начале прописать смену названия окна (по времени, по ID и т.д.): `title my_window` . А только потом запуск процесса NodeJS. Завершить же процесс, чьё окно имеет определенное название, ещё проще: `taskkill /f /fi "windowtitle eq my_window*"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:
taskkill /F /IM node.exe